# How to get the content of a chatter file using API

Tags: rest-api, chatter-file, chatter-api

I am integrating my SF org with an external mobile app.
I have a file uploaded to the chatter feed of each contact (the picture of the contact).

This app needs to get the picture to display in the app.
How to I get this file (picture)?
Which API to use?

Answer (score 1):

You need an identifier for the picture you upload on the chatter feed of contact.Without an identifier you wont be able to identify from the JSON feed .

The API that you can ideally use is

```
/services/data/v35.0/chatter/feeds/record/0039000001CvWno/feed-elements
```

Where the Id i have there is a contact Id .The difficult part of this approach would be parsing out the JSON feed to get the exact content out.The JSON would look something like below

[image]

You will need to trace the feed page to read the  download URL of content or contentId and hence use download URL to get to the picture .All this is assuming you have an identifier rule specified for picture upload(May be contact firstName+lastName.jpg);

The other alternative could be using query API to run a SOQL and get the result directly from the contact feed

**SOQL**

```
SELECT Id,Type,ContentFileName,ContentData
                              FROM ContactFeed 
                              WHERE ParentId = '0039000001CvWno' 
                              AND Type='ContentPost' 
                              ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

**Since contentFileName cannot be filtered you can loop over and use if clause to filter .**

*ContentData would have base64 encoded data of the file*

*ParentId would be the Id of the contact*

REST equivalent of this would be

```
/services/data/v35.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Type,ContentFileName,ContentData+FROM+ContactFeed++WHERE+ParentId+=+'0039000001CvWno'+and+Type='ContentPost'+ORDER+BY+CreatedDate+DESC
```

[image]

> Again all this would work assuming you have strict naming convention rule for the images loaded by user in the contact chatter feed.

Comment: I see that the ContentData is a URL. How to I get the Base64 content

Comment: Make the rest call again with that url

Comment: and if I use the chatter api, I take the 'downloadUrl' field and how to I use it to get the file itself?

Comment: the download URL again needs to be hit from the client (mobile app) in your case .

Comment: if I do this https://eu5.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/chatter/files/06924000000TfeuAAC/content?versionNumber=1 will I get the file? When I try it in the browser I get 'INVALID_SESSION_ID' error

Comment: You need session Ids to hit REST API .Use Curl to test all these commands or workbench .Using curl will help you here since these are of MIME types

Comment: Using workbench it's working fine, but when I try via the mobile app, I get the  'INVALID_SESSION_ID' error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34138/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-dedo).

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am having the same issue.